# referents of they

Tags: pronouns

I am not sure whether the following uses of *they* are acceptable in educated speech when referring to a singular referent:

1. I swear more when I'm talking to a boy because I'm not afraid of shocking *them*.
2. No girl should have to wear school uniform because it makes *them* look like a sack of potatoes.
3. I had a friend in Paris, and *they* had to visit the doctor for a month.
4. A teacher asked me to give *their* book to John.

Answer (score 1):

> I swear more when I'm talking to **boys** because I'm not afraid of shocking **them**.

better matches plurality.

> **No girl** should have to wear *a* school uniform because it makes them look like a sack of potatoes.

*no girl* is not specific, so using *them* is OK. However:

> **Girls** should *not* have to wear *a* school uniform because it makes **them** look like a sack of potatoes.

would be more natural.

> I had **a friend** in Paris, and **he/she** had to visit the doctor for a month.

Obviously you know the gender of the friend, so just use it.

> **A teacher** asked me to give **his/her** book to John.

Again, you know the gender of the teacher, so use it.

Comment: I agree, subject and predicate must match in number. "Gender neutral" `they` for singular seems against nature. Even `it` is more suited, if a new word (the better solution) is not desired to be created. I mean, English is already quite confusing as it is, why cripple it even more?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that **1** is correct because it implies you are talking about all boys in the plural, not just the one you are swearing at.

I would say that **2** is correct because again you are implying many girls.

**3** I would say is not correct and the correct word would be *he* or *she*, but by using *they* you can cover both sexes at once.

**4** Again this simply covers the case for not declaring the sex of the teacher.  In our politically correct world I expect this term to become more used so as not to draw attention to those who feel they are neither he or she.

Answer (score 0):

[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/they) give this among their examples of gender-neutral *they*:

> ‘I mentioned this to someone at work today and *they* looked at me as if I were a space alien.’

In a usage note, Oxford comment that, recently:

> *they* is now being used to refer to specific individuals (as in *Alex is bringing their laptop*).

Your question was, in effect, whether gender-neutral *they* was acceptable in "educated speech" in cases where the gender of the referent *is* already known - as in Oxford's example above.

In my experience, the answer is *yes*.

Still, there remain some who would criticise such usage, as the other responses to your question show.  Even in contexts where the referent's gender is unknown, there are prescriptivists who would prefer to avoid *they*, though their number and influence are undoubtedly diminishing, and on the whole they are more likely to object to written use than to spoken.

(I agree with user3169 that the first two sentences would sound more natural in the plural, and I also agree with Ermintrude that even if those two sentences are left as they are, they are less likely to raise objections than the other two, because the listener might interpret "them" as shorthand for "the girls" or "the boys" rather than as a gender-neutral singular.)